# JQM pagebeforechange and event source

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

listening to pagebeforechange event...

$(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function ( event , data) {

//event is triggered from an anchor tag...
//Is it possible to get reference to anchor( or event.srcElement)  here

});

or
.....

A simple sample below if somebody want to try it out...

```
    <head>
      <title>Main menu</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css"
      />
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function (event, data) {
              if (typeof data.toPage === "string") {
                  //event is triggered from an anchor tag...
                  //Is it possible to get reference to anchor( or event.srcElement)  here
                  event.preventDefault();
              }
          });
      </script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a"></div>
        <div data-role="content">
          <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li>
              <a href="#category-items?category=animals">Animals</a>
            </li> 
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Please see if the following answer helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106172/determine-caller-of-jquery-mobiles-pagebeforechange-event/21969490#21969490

Comment: See if my answer below answers your question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106172/determine-caller-of-jquery-mobiles-pagebeforechange-event/21969490#21969490

Answer (score 0):

How about 
    event.liveFired.activeElement;

Comment: I see the event.liveFired in ff and chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am not sure the way which we are debugging is same or not. I debug by putting a break point in line 9 and type event in console... below is what I can see.

Comment: event
f.Event
currentTarget: HTMLDocument
data: undefined
exclusive: undefined
handleObj: Object
handler: function (event, data) {
jQuery164008264115359634161: true
namespace: ""
namespace_re: /(^|\.)(\.|$)/
result: undefined
target: HTMLBodyElement
timeStamp: 1328713807837
type: "pagebeforechange"
__proto__: Object

Comment: Sorry, I had pagebeforecreate instead of pagebeforechange . I tried your code above and I can see an event.currentTarget.activeElement object that should give you what you need.

Comment: event.currentTarget.activeElement is not giving right element... its giving the div which is having data-role=page

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? I have a similar problem in that I'm trying to the the data-url of the link that was clicked.

Comment: jQuery fires the "clicK" event before any jqm events, so simply attach a "click" event to your anchor element, attach the "ID" to the anchor's closest "data-role='page'" div and reference it with jqm's "pagebeforechange" event.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106172/determine-caller-of-jquery-mobiles-pagebeforechange-event/21969490#21969490