# determine caller of jQuery Mobile's pagebeforechange event

Tags: jquery-mobile

I think this is the same question as [JQM pagebeforechange and event source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179096/jqm-pagebeforechange-and-event-source), but there was no conclusive answer there.

Does anyone know how to get the object that triggered the event?

```js
$(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function ( event , data) {
    //event is triggered from an anchor tag... 
    //Is it possible to get reference to anchor here?
});
```

Thanks.

Fuller example:

```html
<div data-role="page" id="ANGRY">
<div data-role="header">
    Solo Questions</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Since your last scheduled prompt, how <strong>angry</strong> have you felt?</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="ANGRY" value="1" id="ANGRY1" />
        <label for="ANGRY1">
            None</label>
        <input type="radio" name="ANGRY" value="2" id="ANGRY2" />
        <label for="ANGRY2">
            Some</label>
        <input type="radio" name="ANGRY" value="3" id="ANGRY3" />
        <label for="ANGRY3">
            A Lot</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a href="#HAPPY" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">prev</a></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <a href="#IRRITABL" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">next</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to determine what triggered the pagebeforechange event - the "prev" button or the "next" button. The purpose of this to perform validation before moving to the next page, but not when going back to the previous page.

Comment: In examining the event and data objects returned and searching jQuery Mobile's github, it appears that this is not possible. I'm going to just modify the href to call a javascript function that will then do $.mobile.changePage(). If anyone has any other ideas, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

Does the toPage work for this?

- http://jsfiddle.net/pK6GX/1/

JS

```
$(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function ( event , data) {
    console.log('To Page: '+data.toPage);
});​
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <p>Open up the console and Click the Info link</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="info">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

Comment: I see what you're saying - use the toPage to determine which one was clicked. Unfortunately for my scenario, the toPage won't give me enough information as I have a lot of pages with prev and next buttons. So the toPage of a next button is the toPage of a prev button as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is less elegant that I would prefer, but it works for my solution (and I think your solution).  jQuery calls any `click` events before it calls any `page` events, such as `pagebeforechange`.  I simply forced my anchor elements to attach their ID to their `data-role="page"` container.

First:

```
$('a[href="#ce"]').on('click',function(){
    $(this).closest('div[data-role="page"]').attr('data-caller',$(this).attr('id'));
});
```

I am now using `data-caller` to determine which anchor was just clicked on.

Next:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforechange',function(event,data){
    //makes sure that a valid link is actually clicked and ignores init
    if (data.toPage.toString().indexOf('#')>-1 && $(data.options.fromPage).attr('data-url')!==undefined){
            //Determines which page jqm is changing to
            if(data.toPage.split('#')[1]=='ce'){
                switch($('#'+_from).attr('data-caller')){
                    case 'ID_of_anchor_1':
                        //UNIQUE CODE FOR ANCHOR 1
                        break;
                    case 'ID_of_anchor_2':
                        //UNIQUE CODE FOR ANCHOR 2
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Finally, depending on your new page, you might want to remove the `data-caller` attribute on your `data-direction=“reverse”` so it's not accidentally called again.